# how to change a json response

Tags: python, json, discord, roblox

i want to know if i can do response["rap"] == "null" then response["rap"] == "account is private"

im new to python / json reason for bad sytax an example of the api with response null is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWXys.png

i included full code so you can test it out and play about with the code to see if you can get it to work

thanks for reading this

````
async def on_me

    global rap
    global response1234
    response1234 = requests.get(f'http://api.chloe.to/rbx?method=username&user={id}').json()

    rap = response["rap"]
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

    if rap == response["null"]:
        rap = "Private Account"
@bot.command()
async def account(ctx, id):
  response2 = response1234["id"] 
  id2r = discord.Embed()
  id2r.set_author(name='Status : Online', icon_url='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/greenline/512/check-512.png')
  id2r.set_thumbnail (url=response1234["avatar"])
  id2r.add_field(name='***Username ***', value=response1234["username"],inline = False)
  id2r.add_field(name='***RAP ***', value=f"{rap}",inline = False)
  id2r.add_field(name='***Rolimons Link***', value=f"https://www.rolimons.com/player/{response2}",inline = False)
  id2r.timestamp = datetime.now()
  await ctx.send(embed=id2r)
@account.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.UserInputError):
    support = discord.Embed()
    support.set_author(name='Status : Online', icon_url='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/greenline/512/check-512.png')
    support.set_thumbnail (url='https://i.gifer.com/VG4s.gif')
    support.add_field(
      name='***Error***', value='Did Not Provide Roblox Username', inline=False)
    support.timestamp = datetime.now()
    await ctx.send(embed=support)```
````

Comment: Yes, of course you can assign a variable to whatever value you want.

Comment: in the sample response you attached, `null` is not a string. You need to make a check using `None`. For example like this: `response["rap"] == None and response["rap"] == "account is private"` . `None` in python is equivalent of `null` in json